# Unit testing an AngularJS directive which uses scrollposition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which listens to the scroll event, and then adds a class (to make it stick to the top).

My question is how I can test this behaviour? Should I mock $window, or is there a better way to do this? I could look into doing a scenario test, but it seems overkill for just testing a small directive.

The directive looks like this:

```
directiveModule.directive('whenFilterScroll',function($window){
    return function(scope, element, attr){
        var logoHeight = 110;
        angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function(){
            if(this.pageYOffset > logoHeight && element.css('position') != 'fixed')
            {
                element.addClass('filtersFixed');
            }
            if(this.pageYOffset < logoHeight && element.css('position') == 'fixed')
            {
                element.removeClass('filtersFixed');
            }   
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Option #1: mock $window object

Yes, you would mock $window. It isn't overkill for a small directive because your directive relies on it and only on that. From what you're saying, if you aren't testing that with mocks you aren't testing it at all and then how can you be sure your directive works?

No matter how small the file or the class or the method, it should always be backed by a test.

## Option #2: don't mock $window, split your code into smaller testable functions

If you don't want to use a mock, you can rewrite your code so that it does each step in parts and lets you supply the variables, like this:

```
var shouldAddFilterClass = function (pageYOffset, logoHeight, cssPosition) {
    return pageYOffset > logoHeight && cssPosition != 'fixed';
};

var shouldRemoveFilterClass = function (pageYOffset, logoHeight, cssPosition) {
    return pageYOffset < logoHeight && cssPosition == 'fixed';
};

/* ...rest of code... */
angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
  if (shouldAddFilterClass(this.pageYOffset, logoHeight, element.css('position'))) {
    element.addClass('filtersFixed');
  }
  if (shouldRemoveFilterClass(this.pageYOffset, logoHeight, element.css('position'))) {
    element.removeClass('filtersFixed');
  }
});
```

Then in your tests you can do this:

```
assert(shouldAddFilterClass(100, 50, 'static') === true);
assert(shouldRemoveFilterClass(100, 50, 'static') === false);

assert(shouldAddFilterClass(100, 200, 'fixed') === false);
assert(shouldRemoveFilterClass(100, 200, 'fixed') === true);
```

That way you're checking the conditions that are checked by the callback. You can then test to make sure the element has the correct CSS classes. All that without mocking $window.